# Storing multiple selected cells of type string from a datagridview to a list

Tags: c#, list, datagridview

I am working on a C# windows application where I have a DataGridView some some data on it. 
Now, I am trying to select multiple cells and want to access the values in the selected cells and store them in a list. I was able to store one cell in a variable but not sure I can get multiple cell values to a list

I used the following lines to store cell value in a variable

```
 string product = dataGridViewIndex.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();
```

**May I know a way to solve this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty Simple iterate through the selected cells as follows

```
            List<String> listProducts = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridViewIndex.SelectedCells.Count;i++)
            {
                listProducts.Add(dataGridViewIndex.SelectedCells[i].Value.ToString());
            }
```